# Want to take alternative numbers of an array and reverse them in Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, reverse

Want to take even numbers from an array and reverse them and Put it again in the place of array again. My Array:

```
[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8]
```

Required Output: `[1,8,3,6,5,4,7,2]`

Just want to know logic.Any suggestion
tell me ?

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow! You seem to be under the impression that StackOverflow is a site where you post a problem and get some code in return. This is in fact not the case. Your question will most likely be closed or even deleted shortly. To prevent this from happening in the future, please [take the tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and [take a look at the help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help). In particular, [make yourself famlilar as to what is regarded as on-topic around here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)

Comment: @NomadMaker I would already be happy, if they didn't aswell get upvoted for it.

Comment: I was expecting only logic, either in java or javascript or any other language.

Comment: @NomadMaker  Its valid question, can we reopen it.

Comment: I have no objection, but I didn't vote to close it.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Please write code logic like this.

```
public class ReverseEven {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        int ar[] = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8};
        for (int i = 0; i < ar.length; i++) {
            if (ar[i] % 2 != 0) {
                System.out.print(" " + ar[i]);
            } else {
                for (int j = ar.length - i; j >= 0; j--) {
                    if (ar[j] % 2 == 0) {
                        System.out.print(" " + ar[j]);
                        break;
                    }

                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You can implement this logic in javascript also.